# What does "take away" mean in combinatoric questions: why divide instead of subtract?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, examples-counterexamples

I dislike combinatorial questions because I am not a native English speaker, and this entire field uses non-rigorous language, such as "placing", "choosing", "taking away" and uses playful examples like poker game, which uses words like "diamond" or "spade" that are foreign to me.

The biggest challenge for me right now is to trying to understand why we divide instead of subtract in doing combinatoric questions.

---

*Example: A farmer is planting 5 red flowers, 3 yellow flowers, and 2 white flowers in a row. How many different ways can the farmer plant these flowers?*

Ok, so I answer this question like this:

Imagine we have a list of boxes that we can place these flowers in:

[][][][][][][][][][]

The first box can take on 5+3+2 = 10 flowers, next 9....so in total we have 10*9*8....*1 = 10! possible ways, if all flowers are labelled.

Since these flowers are not labelled, now I need to "take away" those "repeated" flowers. ("Taking away" - At least this is what teachers or textbook usually say)

*Ok, so what does "take away" mean? Thought experiment:If I had 5 apples, I take away 3, I have 2 left. Aha! So 5 - 3 = 2. Taking away means subtract!*

Since each of these 5 red flowers can be arranged in 5*4*3*2*1 = 5! ways, yellow flowers in 3! ways, and white flowers in 2! ways.

Therefore, the total number of ways the farmer can arrange these flowers is 10!-5!3!2!.

---

**Why am I wrong in this approach?
Why is the correct approach is to divide 10! by 5!3!2!?**

Comment: If you label all the flowers from A to J and list all the ways you can place them in order, you will see that some color patterns will appear twice. For example if if "A" and "B" are the two white flowers, then switching the position of "A" and "B" in any given ordering will not change the color pattern. In your list of all $10!$ orderings of A,B,...,J, each color pattern is represented multiple times; actually, each color pattern is represented exactly $5! 3! 2!$ times. That is why you divide by $5!3!2!$.

Comment: This might not be too helpful, but decide for yourself: your first counting defines a surjective function $f : X\to Y$, but this is not injective: the fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in Y$ all have a fixed number of elements, say $N$. The division amounts to identifying all the elements in such preimages to one arrangement, so you end up dividing $X$ into equivalence classes, and end up with $\# X/N$ options in total.

Comment: If English is not your first language, you will inevitably encounter confusing colloquial uses. If you have packs of 52 cards divided into 4 suits is your own culture, they will have the same underlying structure, whatever the suits are called (in English: Spades, Hearts, Diamonds and Clubs). These are used for examples because they are familiar objects. On your other point, the issue is to take account of options which have been counted more than once in a first (crude) estimate. How this is done mathematically does not depend on the informal language used to describe what needs to be done.

Comment: @MarkBennet I thought opaque meant "transparent" for the longest time. I had a great time calculating probability of "drawings" various colored balls from opaque jars.

Comment: Nobody other than you used the words "take away", hinting at a subtraction, for an instance where clearly a division is called for.  I think your language is openly impertinent and should not be honored with friendly answers.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Plenty of people use the term "take away". The colloquial definition of "take away" hints at subtraction, not division. See the accepted answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1585120/what-is-the-probability-of-matching-exactly-4-numbers/1585127

Comment: @StrayCat in that example "take away all 6 from 49" does indeed mean subtraction.  It is not an example of using the words to hint at division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always think of it this way:

n! = number of unique permutations * number of times each unique permutation is copied

where n is the number of objects you are permuting. So if we divide n! by the number of times each permutation is copied, we get the right number. In your case, n=10 and each unique arrangement of flowers is copied 5!*3!*2! times

Comment: This is a good formula to have. But then it begs the question, why not ADD the number of unique permutations with the copied permutations? Wouldn't that give you the "total" number of permutations? You see where I am getting at? Unique ones + copied ones = total, unique ones * copied ones = ???

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you could do that. You would end up with the same formula though because the number of copied ones is directly related to the number of unique ones. n! = number of unique permutations + number of unique permutations * (number of times copied - 1). The reason for the -1 is because one of the copies is already present in the first part of the sum

Comment: In other words, 5!*3!*2! is not the "total number of copies". It is the total number of copies of $\textbf{one}$ specific arrangement of flowers. So to get the total for all arrangements of flowers, you need to multiply by the number of unique arrangements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So it is more like: n! = number of unique permutations * number of times each "unique" permutation is copied

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.